# Text editor with indexing feature

Tags: open-source

I would like to know which text editor comes with an indexing feature.

Basically index the given folder which has .txt files inside the folder.

Thanks.

Comment: I know of no editors that do this natively by themselves, but [ctags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) and it's various derivatives are pretty widely supported by a lot of text editors and can provide this functionality.

Comment: What do you want to do with this index? Notepad++ can search for patterns through a folder

Comment: Doncarlos but it cannot index and the search is not much faster when the number of files are huge 10,00,000 or 50,00,000

Comment: for giant amounts of data you shouldn't use a text editor anyway, but rather a search engine like Apache Lucene